# Else statement being run even when if statement is true?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to establish a verification system for a form, whereas one of the `input` elements is called `verification`. The form should only be submitted (as an email to someone else) if the value of `verification` is 108 — which works. However, when I run my code, I find that the code inside the `else` statement (of the embedded if-statement) also runs, and I get a popup window that asks me what `3+105` is. Why is this?

**HTML**

```
<form class="pb-5" action="" method="POST">
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="inputName4">Name</label>
         <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="inputName"
            name="name" 
            value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"
            required
            />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="inputCompany">Company</label>
         <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="inputCompany"
            name="company" 
            value="<?php echo isset($_POST['company']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['company'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"
            required
            />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="subject">Subject</label>
         <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="subject"
            name="subject" 
            value="<?php echo isset($_POST['subject']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"
            required
            />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
         <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="inputEmail"
            name="email" 
            value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"
            required
            />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="verification">What is 5+103?</label>
      <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control"
         id="verification"
         name="verification" 
         required
         ></input>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textarea">Message</label>
      <textarea
         class="form-control"
         id="textarea"
         rows="3"
         name="message" 
         required
         ><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES) : ''; ?>"</textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3">
   Send
   </button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
    $verification = $_POST["verification"];
    settype($verification, "integer");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         if($verification == 108) {
              mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
              echo "<script> alert('Thank you for your mail!')</script>";
         } elseif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) === false) {
              echo "<script> alert('An error has occurred.')</script>";
         } else {
              echo "<script> alert('What is 3+105?')</script>";
         }
    } else {
         return;
    }
```

If I can clarify my issue in any way, please do not hesitate to let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your html & javascript form?

Comment: What does `var_dump($verification, $_POST["verification"])` give?

Comment: @Alex I have now updated my post accordingly!

Comment: @user3783243 It gives ``int(108) string(3) "108"``.

Comment: and `var_dump($verification == 108)` gives `bool(false)`?

Comment: @user3783243 It gives ``bool(true)`` actually.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify the circumstances when you are getting the `alert` in that case. The `else`  wouldn't be fired in that scenario. Add error logging in each scenario so you can see the execution behavior. `if($verification == 108) { error_log('108 was matched'); } elseif ... { error_log('elseif was entered');` etc.

Comment: in that case, what you are claiming should not be possible. Are you sure it's all happening within the same request? Add some more logging

Comment: @ADyson Yeah that's what I was confused by. If the ``if`` returns true then the ``else`` shouldn't get executed...

Comment: @user3783243 Do you think it could have anything to do with the fact that I'm handling the submission in the same file as I have the form?

Comment: _"handling the submission in the same file as I have the form"_ that shouldn't matter, because you're doing it all inside a block which tests whether the request is a POST or not. Is there any circumstance in which the form gets submitted more than once, or by AJAX, or there are other forms which send to the same script?

Comment: @ADyson There's only one form, and I'm not using AJAX. I don't believe that the form is submitted more than once, can I double-check this somehow? Also, tried adding a few error logs but only the one in the embedded if-statement gets logged. In fact, the error log inside the embedded ``if`` is not logged at all even when the mail gets sent...

Comment: "can I double-check this somehow" ...use your browser's Developer Tools and watch the Network requests going back and forth. And/or add some logging to the PHP - make it write to a file so you can see how many times the code is running, and when, and which bits are being executed.

Comment: P.S. you know that `} elseif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) === false) {
              echo "<script> alert('An error has occurred.')</script>";
         }` really doesn't make much sense? 1) you already know it's a POST because of the outer `if` statement and 2) this will (try to) send an email - but I got the impression you only wanted to send an email if $verification is 108?

Comment: If `$verification` is not 108 and you post the form, you end up in the `elseif` where the mail is also send.

Comment: @ADyson @Michel Oh, my bad. I thought that it simply compared whether or not the mail had been sent or not. I've removed the ``elseif`` statement for now, and the email is not sent at all. I'm a bit confused as to why it isn't sent? When I log the value of ``$verification`` it turns up as an integer with the value of 108.

Comment: "I thought that it simply compared whether or not the mail had been sent"...not clear why you'd think that? The command is identical to the other command which is designed to send a mail, so why would you expect two identical commands to behave differently? Not a criticism as such - we've all made plenty of coding mistakes in our time, just posing the question as food for thought in future, with the hope you can make more logical assumptions about your code in future :-).

Comment: Because the command in the ``elseif`` was intended (same intent as Michel's answer) to compare (with false) whether or not the email had been sent. But yeah still new to this so I guess sometimes the logic fails in my brain...

Comment: Yes I understand the intent, but wondered why you thought it would make a comparison rather than just repeating the send operation.

Comment: anyway... "the email is not sent at all"...ok so now you need to test whether the call to `mail` inside the `if($verification == 108)` a) happens at all, and b) succeeds. Also there's a big difference between _sending_ an email and _receiving_ an email. A lot can go wrong in between those two events, and not all of it is within your control as the PHP programmer. So first you need to find out if `mail` is at least managing to send the mail to the mailserver or not.

Comment: Oh because I thought that I was comparing the value of what it was returning. So I thought comparing whether it was false or not (sent or not) would not actually call it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Not really. `mail()` does the same thing every time you call it. And it always returns a value. The only difference is, one of the times you called you chose not to read the returned value, and the other time you did. But the `mail()` function doesn't know whether you did that or not. Consider this simple example: `function foo(){ echo "foo"; return true;} foo(); $x = foo();  if ($x == true) echo "yes";` The function foo will always echo "foo", regardless of whether you test what it returns or not. It has no way of knowing what you do with its output.

Comment: Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62c71b02a8af521297d6aff1cc2f19e565ad1792 . If you consider the echoing of "foo" to be analgous to the sending of an email, you'll hopefully get my point.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah I get you, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have to rewrite your `if ... else ...`

```
$verification = $_POST["verification"];
settype($verification, "integer");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if($verification == 108) {
      //TEST IF MAIL IS CORRECTLY SEND
      if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) === false){
         echo "<script> alert('An error has occurred.')</script>";
         }
      else{
         echo "<script> alert('Thank you for your mail!')</script>";
         }
   }
   else {
      echo "<script> alert('What is 3+105?')</script>";
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked fantastically! I'm just curious though, when I removed my ``elseif`` statement, it still did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing what you changed. Could have been verification not 108, wrong nesting of if else or something different.

Comment: Essentially was the same code as in the question without an ``elseif`` statement. Got a bit desperate for it to work, haha..

Comment: One tip: move `$verification =` and `settype` inside `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_ME...){` If the method is not POST, you don't need the variable  `$verification` at all.